# how to check function execution time & return if it is taking more than 10 seconds to execute

Tags: php, laravel

I have one function & wants to calculate total execution time. If it is taking more than 10 seconds to execute then return from the function & break the loop.

I have code to calculate execution time but not getting how to return if it is taking more than 10 seconds to execute.

```
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++) {

  $time_start = microtime(true);

 //call funtion
 show(10);

 $time_end = microtime(true);

 //Total execution time
 $total_time = $time_end - $time_start;
 echo "Exe Time: ". $total_time;
}


function show() {
    sleep(4);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

unfortunately, timeout errors cannot be caught in php, but you can almost do this with simple math & microtime(),

```
function f(int max_execution_time=10){
$starttime=microtime(true);
//do stuff here
if((microtime(true)-$starttime) > $max_execution_time){
    return ETIMEDOUT;
}
//do more stuff here
if((microtime(true)-$starttime) > $max_execution_time){
    return ETIMEDOUT;
}
// and more stuff here, and repeat
if((microtime(true)-$starttime) > $max_execution_time){
    return ETIMEDOUT;
}    
// and finally, 
return SUCCESS;
}
```

wherever you see appropriate, just check if it should timeout or not. this is not very accurate as you cannot set a time limit for most functions (eg, if your function is calling file_get_contents(), you cannot set a time limit for file_get_contents() short of using set_time_limit(), but the errors generated by set_time_limit cannot be caught and will terminate the whole php script :( )

Comment: cant we set timeout

Comment: @Omi that's what the input argument is for. `function f(int max_execution_time=10){`  - max execution time can be decided at call-time, but is 10 seconds by default.  `f(15)`, now the max time is 15 seconds. `f(5)`, now the timeout is 5 seconds, `f(100)`, now the timeout is 100 seconds.